# Draw line in code behind that auto adjusts on screen resize

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I need to draw a line in code behind that starts at a specifc X,Y point and ends at a specific X,Y points. These points will never change but as the canvas size is adjusted the line will need to adjust.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just draw the line over the horizontal canvas size and refresh the canvas as soon as it gets resized? Should be pretty trivial.

Comment: Have you got an example please?